# Sharing the state of a report in Power BI app

Tags: powerbi

It's possible to share a report in Power BI in the state that I see it - the state of Slicers, the level of hierarchy, etc. - by clicking on Share, and checking "Include my changes".

But how do I do this, when the report is published in a Power BI app? Is there a way to share a link to a report in the app that would preserve changes made by the user sending it?

I can still see the Share button, and I tried using it, but now it doesn't give me the "Include my changes" option, and when recipients open the generated link, they don't see the state of the report that I saw, but some state that's default for them.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is indeed lacking when in an app.

A "hack" is to use the "Chat in Teams" option. When the window pops-open, you can copy that link which should end in `bookmarkGuid={guid}`.

**Note** that this isn't a share link, as in it won't add new users to app/report. Instead, it is simply a link to the app/report with any pre-selected filters that existing app users can use.